Adapted Charts and pullback of a $1$-form via the inclusion map
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function, $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be a regular value and $S=F^{-1}(c)$ be the corresponding regular level set. By the Regular Level Set Theorem, $S$ is an embedded submanifold.
In view of the proof of the Regular Level Set Theorem, taking the variables $x^{j_k}$ such that $\det(\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^{j_k}}_{| p}) \neq 0$ ($i,k=1,\dots,m$) and replacing them with $F_1,\dots,F_m$, we get a coordinate system near $p$.
I have three questions:

May I use the implicit function theorem to get a new coordinate system near $p$? As an example, if $S$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is $(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ a coordinate system near a point $p$ of the upper hemisphere?

My attempt
A coordinate system near $p \in S$ should be given by an adapted chart, so a finite number of coordinates must vanish at $p$. Actually, $(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ is the inverse of $\phi^+_2: U^+_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$. Thus, it is not a coordinate system on $S^2$ (I think this is the coordinate representative of the inclusion map of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$, with coordinates $r,s,t$)

Let now $i: S \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the inclusion map. How can I express the coordinate representative of $i$ with respect to the previous adapted chart near $p$?

My attempt
Calling $x^{j_t}$ the other variables (for instance $1,\dots,n-m$), then $\phi_S^{-1}: \phi_S(U_S) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-m} \to U_S \subseteq S$ is given by
$$
(x^1,\dots,x^{n-m}) \mapsto (x^1,\dots,x^{n-m},F^1,\dots,F^m)
$$
Hence $i \circ \phi_S^{-1}(x^1,\dots,x^{n-m})=(x^1,\dots,x^{n-m},F^1,\dots,F^m)$.

Next, let $\omega$ be a smooth $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider its pullback $i^\ast \omega$ by the inclusion $i: S \to \mathbb{R}^n$. For instance, let $\omega=x^1dx^1+\dots+x^ndx^n$. Then $i^\ast \omega=x^1dx^1+\dots+x^ndx^n$. But what happens if we use the adapted chart?

My attempt
We have $i^\ast \omega=x^1dx^1+\dots+x^{n-m}dx^{n-m}+F^1dF^1+\dots+F^mdF^m=x^1dx^1+\dots+x^{n-m}dx^{n-m}$
Is it possible to receive a point-by-point answer, please?
